# Django - What is the best way to store in the DB answers that can be numerical or text?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I'm working on a student survey project. The model that stores the questions is something like:

```
ID     Question                 Type 
1      is good teacher?         Choice 
2      What do you like about   Open-answer
       the teacher?
```

Then in the `choice` type questions the student will choose an option (e.g.: fully agree) and this will store a numerical code (e.g. 5). But in the open-answer questions , the student will write text.

what kind of field should store these answers in the `answers model`? maybe TextField?

Comment: Are you asking an implementation for django admin ?

Comment: @scharette No, I am not talking about admin, I am talking in general way, I mean, for production

Comment: Depends most how do you want to use your data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ur choices as text if you want to use same column to open text... so instead of set 1,2,3,4 you can write a fixed text when user select the options, so this make your data more readeble

```
ANSWER = (
    ("Yes", "Yes"),
    ("No", "No"),
    ("Neutral", "Neutral"),
)
```

Or make 2 more columns... one to set type of question (select or text) and the other to store the options (that way you can setup as foreign key and instead of use static values this can be loaded from one model)

```
ID     Question                 Type             Answer-Text         AnswerID 
1      is good teacher?         Choice           null                1
2      What do you like about   Open-answer      "The way he swag"   null
       the teacher?
```

Or mix everything with String... but you will have some troubles getting this integer ids... will throw some erros when you try to get it as integer int("1") Will work but int("The way he swag") will raise a error

Answer (score 0):

Using a `TextField` would probably be a bad idea since you're mixing `int` with `string` type objects which is definitely not recommended.

One thing you could do is consider this as two different fields. One `Choicefield` and one `TextField`. That way the user can choose an empty value (empty string `''`) when he wants to use the *open-answer*. You can then compute empty strings as being nothing later on.